# How to fix cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In vs code I'm getting this error "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2' [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS1503)".

This is the code where the error appears:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HF_001 : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public enum ForceType { Repulsion = -1, None = 0, Attraction = 1 }
    public ForceType m_Type;
    public Transform m_Pivot;
    public float m_Radius;
    public float m_StopRadius;
    public float m_Force;
    public LayerMask m_Layers;

    
    
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapArea(m_Pivot.position, m_Radius, m_Layers);

        float signal = (float)m_Type;

        foreach (var collider in colliders)
        {
            Rigidbody2D body = collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            if (body == null) 
                continue;

            Vector2 direction = m_Pivot.position - body.position;

            float distance = direction.magnitude;

            direction = direction.normalized;

            if (distance < m_StopRadius) 
                continue;

            float forceRate = (m_Force / distance);

            body.AddForce(direction * (forceRate / body.mass) * signal);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the type of the variable "m_Radius"

Comment: `OverlapArea` uses a rectangle so it needs two points. Perhaps [OverlapCircle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As per official document on [Physics2D.OverlapArea](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapArea.html). It takes second argument [Vector2](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html) not a float value.

In the above code `public float m_Radius;` is type of float but need to be `Vector2`.

`Physics2D.OverlapArea` is used to check if a Collider falls within a rectangular area where as if you need to use Radius but not a point then please look at  [Physics2D.OverlapCircle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html)